# displaying blogs in webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I want to display my blog as a part of an android application..i have the code ready..it works well when displaying websites like google etc but not with my blog..can someone help me solve this problem

mainActivity.java:

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

    }

}
```

webViewActivity.java:

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

        private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("pavan7vasan.blogspot.com");

    }

}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUrl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go to http://www.google.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

webview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

it shows web page not available in the android emulator

Comment: The url should start with http://

Comment: oh yeah...sorry..I forgot to put that piece of code in the parameter of the loadUrl method

Answer (score 1):

Change this line, and it should work.

```
webView.loadUrl("http://pavan7vasan.blogspot.com");
```